# "\"@\" is not valid at the start of a code block

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Here is my razor view.

```
@model IEnumerable<ApricaROI.Models.DatabaseEntities.SalesItemMapping>
@{
    var name_List = Model.GroupBy(x => x.Name).Select(y => y.First()).ToList();
}
@foreach (var name in Model.Select(item => item.Name).Distinct()) {
    <div id="item@@name" class='itemDivs'>
        @{ Html.RenderPartial("_EditItemChild",
                     Model.Where(item => item.Name== name).ToList()); }
    </div>
}
```

I don't know what kind of error it has. It is giving following error.

```
"\"@\" is not valid at the start of a code block.
Only identifiers, keywords, comments, \"(\" and \"{\" are valid.\r\n"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is in id="item@@name".  You can't have @@ there.  Razor is using @ character.  In cases where the content is valid as code as well (and you want to treat it as content), you can explicitly escape out @ characters by typing @@.  So in your case you will have id="item@name" after Razor parse it.

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

If you need to use variable inside please use

```
<div id="item@(name)" class='itemDivs'>
```

Comment: I read online that to escape @, @ is used. So I used it. And yes that's the problem but if I remove it, it become string in my id. I want to use variable there.

Comment: Doesn't I keep id as itemName1 or itemName2 like wise... (Name1 and Name2 are values of name variable)?

Comment: in that case please use <div id="item@(name)" class='itemDivs'>

Answer (score 10):

I have read somewhere that `@@` works in `mvc3` i.e. `razor 1.0`. But somehow doesnt work in `mvc4 razor-2.0`

So try Changing

```
<div id="item@@name" class='itemDivs'>
```

to

```
<div id="item@("@name")" class='itemDivs'>
```

Answer (score -1):

use this code instead :

```
<div id="item@name" class="itemDivs">

</div>
```